# Run group of commands under one PID

Tags: unix, zsh

Is it possible to run multiple commands in Zsh in such a way that killing one PID would kill all the commands?

For example, suppose I entered the following:

```
python3 longscript1; python3 longscript2
```

Suppose python was still executing longscript1, and I wanted to kill both longscript1 AND longscript 2 with a command like this:

kill -9

How would I do that?

Comment: These are independent commands, thee is nothing linking them together.  Unless the first one forks the second command, there is no relationship that will allow that.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the group of commands in a subshell  with:

```
zsh -c 'python3 longscript1; python3 longscript2'
```

and then kill the zsh subshell.